# Restricting access to webpage to administrators only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page called "adminarea.php" and this page should only be acccessible by administrators. Within my database on the user table i have a column called "userLevel" and this column has values of either "1" or "0", in this case a "0" means the user is an administrator.

Now when a user clicks on a link which leads to "adminarea.php" the code below exists. I believe I may be missing something which should make the code access the database and analyse the column which holds the information in regards as to whether the user who is trying to access the page is an administrator or not.

```
<?php require "header.php";

if(check_login() && isAdmin()) {

} else {
   header('Location: login.php');
   exit;
}

function isAdmin() {
if (intval($_SESSION['sess_uid']['userLevel']) < 1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}

}

function check_login () {
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_uid']) && $_SESSION['sess_uid'] != '') {
   return true;
} else {
   false;
}
}



?>
```

A second set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: probably `return` is missing in `check_login` function near the `false;`

Comment: hmm it doesn't appear to be that, when i log in as a non administrator i can still access the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the database. If you are using PDO, you could do this.

```
function isAdmin() {
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT `userLevel` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['sess_uid']);
    try {
        $query->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    $userLevel = $query->fetchColumn();
    return $userLevel == 1;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. i am using mysqli although originally using mysql functions.

Comment: Do I need to write it in MySQLi for you?

Comment: No, just letting you know! im changing what you've shown to mysqli